# What's the difference between [[]] and [] in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax

Came across this snippet that does :

```
@@dataList[i] = [[0,[]]]
```

What do the double brackets do? What if I wrote :

```
@@dataList[i] = [0,[]]
```

.. would it work any different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[]` is an empty array.

`[[]]` is an array containing an empty array as its single element.

`[0,[]]` is an array containing two elements.

`[[0, []]]` is an array containing one element, which happens to be another array.

Answer (score 4):

One is an array and the other is a nested array.

Consider:

```
a = [[0,[]]]
b = [0,[]]
a[0] # => [0, []]
b[0] # => 0
a.length # => 1
b.length # => 2
```

Answer (score 3):

`[]` - array.
`[[]]` - array in array.

C.O.

Answer (score 2):

the whole thing is just in another array.
Quite a lot of them in this code anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`[0,[]]` is an array of size 2 whose first element is the number 0 and whose second element is an empty array.

`[ [0,[]] ]` is an array of size 1 whose first and only element is an array of size 2.